# Get all arguments after args[0] discord.js

Tags: arguments, discord.js

I was trying to make a mute command, and I was adding a system where you can mute them for a reason. The bot would reply "(Username of user) was muted. Reason: (The reason)". For me args[0] is just mentioning the user that you want to mute, but I can't figure out how to get all after args[0]. I've tried doing something like this `message.channel.send('I have muted' + (mutedUser) + 'Reason: ' + args[1++]`. But that obviously didn't work - I was kind of guessing - I turned to listing 4 arguments like this.

```
message.channel.send('I have muted ' + taggedUser.user.username + ' Reason: ' + args[1] + ' ' + args[2] + ' ' + args[3] + ' ' + args[4])
```

But obviously, that's not very efficient - Does anyone know how to get all arguments after args[0]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the array of `args` and `slice()` the number of arguments you want to delete, then `join()` the remaining array elements into a single string

**Quick Tip**
Use Template literals for easier formatting with strings and variables

```
const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');

message.channel.send(`I have muted ${mutedUser}, Reason: ${reason}`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much - Yours was very easy to understand. As the one which is above with one upvote works as well - I didn't understand it that easily as Im new to discord.js. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const str = 'first second third fourth fifth sixth seventh...';
const args = str.split(' ');

console.log(args[0]); // first
console.log(args.slice(1).join(' ')); // everything after first

console.log(args[3]); // fourth
console.log(args.slice(4).join(' ')); // everything after fourth

// basically, `Array.prototype.join()` can join every element of an array (with an optional separator- in this case a space)
console.log(args.join(' ')); // join all elements with a space in between

// and `Array.prototype.slice()` can slice off elements of an array
console.log(args.slice(5)); // slice off 5 elements

// now you can combine these two :)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But yours was a little hard to understand. That's ok - Both this one and the post by Elitezen work, and I had to look a little into the code but now I figured it out. Thanks for the answer as well:D

Answer (score 2):

In a generic scenario, you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as so:

```
const [foo, ...bar] = args;
```

Here, `foo` is equal to `args[0]` and the rest of `args` is contained within `bar` as an array.

Specific to your case you could probably do this within your command:

```
const [mutedUser, reason] = args;
```

And then as Elitezen suggested, use template literals to send your message.

```
message.channel.send(`I have muted ${mutedUser}, Reason: ${reason}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Yours would work if all the args were the reasons, but args[0] is the mention so when I tried that it but it also said the username of the person mentioned to be muted in the reason. Thanks for answering anyway - I did learn how to do something new, getting all arguments. So thanks:)